# You must supply a resource ID for a TextView error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a problem. It gives an error "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView". Where is the problem, thanks.

SoundList class;

```
public class SoundList extends ListActivity {

int [] soundfile;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
final Activity act = this;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
    soundfile= new int[] {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2};

    String[] newsounds = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newsounds);        
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.list, newsounds));
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {     

          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          intent.putExtra("position", position);
          startActivity(intent);      
      }
    });

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reklam);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "....");
    layout.addView(adView);
     AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
     //request.setTesting(true);
     adView.loadAd(request);

}
```

List_item.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="18dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reklam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error log;

```
11-17 01:43:34.110: E/ArrayAdapter(5118): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2040)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at a android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)  
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:382)
11-17 01:43:34.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5118):     ... 32 more
```

Comment: Your not even using a textview in the code?

Comment: Oh! you have not made a listitem...

Answer (score 5):

It should be like this::

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your main code:
R.id.lable is the ID of the textview you we're supposed to have in your list_item.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.list_item.xml, R.id.label, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Your horrendously doing this incorrectly, i'd recommend taking a look at some tutorials:

make A NEW  XML file called

list_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="18dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reklam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

leave the other stuff how it was and then it should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
```

Comment: I changed but it gives different an error "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"  ; at com.zilsesleri.SoundList.onCreate(SoundList.java:32) this.setContentView(R.layout.list_item);